# Converting date to day of the week, if no date leave blank

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

I am using:

```
=TEXT({K24}, "ddd")
```

But is K24 is blank then the results always equals "Sat" how can I get a blank K24 to result in ""?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Use IF and ISBLANK functions.

Answer (score 1):

Use `if()`, like this:

`=if(K24, text(K24, "ddd"), iferror(1/0))`

Alternatively, use **Format > Number > Custom date and time** to set the date format to **Day as abbreviation**.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one, for example:

<strike>=iferror(TEXT({K24}, "ddd"))</strike>

Since this does not work with reference to a cell, (just to smile) I am writing other three that do work:

```
=TEXT({""&K24}, "ddd")
```

or

```
=TEXT({upper(K24)}, "ddd")
```

or

```
=TEXT({join(,K24)}, "ddd")
```

Comment: I would like the one who gave the -1 to my answer to also give me the motivation ... I still believe that my answer is correct and answers the question exactly. I am always ready to accept any right correction.

Comment: ok... I understand the -1 :)  I had tried with numbers inside the brackets, not with a specific cell ... with numbers it works, with a cell it doesn't.